# Configuración manual DNS

Tags: dns

Soy nuevo con el tema de redes y me gustaría a ver si alguien puede responderme a esta pregunta:
Estoy interesado en usar las DNS de Cloudflare (1.1.1.1 y 1.0.0.1) y dejar de lado las de Google. Si defino, a partir de una conexión manual configurada desde mi pc que quiero las DNS de Cloudflare pero en el router al que yo me conecto sigo teniendo configuradas las de Google, ¿a que dirección de DNS se resolverán mis peticiones cuando yo navege por la web?

No se si estoy siendo muy claro...
Disculpen

Gracias

Comment: va directamente al dns configurado en tu pc la opcion mas simple es cambiar en tu router el dns y dejar la configuracion automatica en tu pc esto hara que todas las maquinas de la red resuelvan con `Cloudflare` sin tener que ir 1 por 1

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la configuración de DNS es estatica, el PC va a usar la direccion de Cloudflare.  Puede ver cual servidora usa el PC con NSLOOKUP o IPCONFIG en Windows o ifconfig (en Linux.)

Comment: Gracias. Pero en nslookup me sale una empezada por 127... Me parece que esa es la dirección loopback, o algo así... no?

Comment: Sipi, 127.0.01 es loopback.  Entonces, en linux puede intentar este:   systemd-resolve --status | grep 'Servers'

Comment: Perfecto. Ahora sí. Muchas gracias!